# How to call the Class destructor when the process is killed with TaskManager?

Tags: c#, process, destructor, kill

As the object says:

How to call the Class destructor when the process is killed with TaskManager?

Comment: nope. task manager will close the process forcefully.

Comment: I've changed my question, sorry

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12313209/491243

Comment: also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706344/what-message-i-receive-when-i-kill-my-program-with-task-manager

Comment: Thank you @491243, I didn't make a good search since the question was slightly different; I think that I will close the question

Answer (score 0):

the class destructor is called upon by the GC, as said in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), meaning it is called by the program. when we close application from the task manager, we forcibly close the program, meaning we don't let the GC go through the object, and even if it did, the GC wouldn't know to release the object, and even if it did, there is no meaning to that because we release all the memory just after